# if 2 compact manifolds has infinity intersection, is there any point such that the tangent space of this point are equals?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, compact-manifolds, tangent-bundle

This question came from more specific question, that I am trying to solve with the above statement.

The specific question is :
Given $M_1, M_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ , smooth compact manifolds, while $M_1$ is 1-dimensional and $M_2$ is 2-dimensional.
Assuming that $M_1 \cap M_2$ is infinity
prove that there exists $x \in M_1 \cap M_2$ such that 
$TxM_1 \subset  TxM_2$.

I managed to prove existence of x, such for any neighborhood of x, $Ux$.

$M_1 \cap M_2  \cap  Ux \neq \{x\}$ , aka for any neighborhood of x, there is point $y$, such that $ x \neq y \in M_1 \cap M_2 \cap  Ux$. could not get any further.

Comment: For finish your argument, one should take a countable family of decreasing neighorhood $U_n$ of $x$ with corresponding points $y_n \in U_n \cap M_1 \cap M_2$, and a smooth curve $\gamma \subset M_2$ passing through all the $y_n$ and $x$. If such curve exists, this would show that $T_xM_1 \subset T_xM_2$ but the problem is, such curve does not need to exist if you pick randomly the $y_n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x \in M_1 \cap M_2$ is such that $T_xM_1 \oplus T_x M_2 = T_x \Bbb R^3$ then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $M_1 \cap U \cap M_2 = \{x\}$. Since $M_1$ is compact it follows that there is only finitely many such $x$.

(Notice that compactness of $M_2$ is not needed.)

Why there is such a neighborhood ? There a neighborhood $V \ni x$ with local coordinates $a,b,c$ around $x$ such that  $M_2 \cap V = \{(a,b,c) \mid c = 0 \}$. Consider a parametrization of $M_1$ given by $\gamma(t) = (a(t),b(t), c(t))$, with $\gamma(0) = x$. On has $c(0) = 0$ by hypothesis, and since $T_xM_1 + T_xM_2 = T_x \Bbb R^3$ we should have $c'(0) \neq 0$. In particular, for $ t> 0$ small enough, $c(t) \neq 0$ so $\gamma(t) \cap M_2 = \emptyset$ and it follows that there is a neighborhood $U \ni x$ with $M_1 \cap M_2 \cap U = \{x\}$.

Comment: i couldn't understand why there is neighborhood  U of x such that  $M_1 \cap U \cap M_2 = \{x\}$

Comment: @IdanPerez : I edited my answer. Don't hesitate to ask if something is still not clear !

Comment: hey @N.H. understand everything till the point of the neighborhood U,
$\gamma(t) \cap M_2  $ contains x , but why there is neighborhood of $\gamma(t)$ such that it contains only x ? 
isn't it possible that any neighborhood  of $\gamma(t)$ will contain more than x ? thank you

Comment: We have $c'(0) \neq 0$, so the function $c(t)$ is strictly increasing (or decreasing) and $c(0) = 0$ so there $\epsilon > 0$ with $c(t) \neq 0$ for $t \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$. If you make the picture this is clear that $(*)$ there is a neighborhood $U$ that intersect only $M_1$ on $\gamma(t)$, but $\gamma(t)$ itself intersect only $M_2$ at $x$ for $t$ small enough.
If you want a more rigourous proof of $(*)$, for all $y \in M_1$, there is $\delta(y) > 0$ such that the set $\gamma(t) + s n$ ($n$ = normal vector), with $0 < s < \delta$ does not intersect $M_1$. $\delta(y)$ is ...

Comment: ... is a continuous function on $M_1$ so around $x$ there is $\delta > 0$ with a neighborhood $T \cong \gamma \times D$ where $D$ is an open disk of radius $\delta$ such that $M_1$ does not intersect $T$ other than $\gamma$ ($T = \{z \in \Bbb R^3 : d(z,\gamma) < \delta\}$ where $\gamma$ is a small portion of the curve.  This is the neighborhood you were looking for.

Comment: thank you, i understand now !

Comment: @IdanPerez Perfect, glad I could help !!